# How to use crud operation in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I facing the issue in the Django crud operation. I tried to create a crud operation using Django. All operations are working fine but update operation only is not working. because I tried to click the edit button and show the data in the edit form and also change the data in the form and click the update button in the URL is changing this type (**http://localhost:8000/show/6/update/6**) . I need this URL (**http://localhost:8000/update/6**). I tried many ways but I could not get an error where is occurred.any one can run my code and give comments. How to solve this issue.

**Project**

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url,include

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('olcapp.urls'))
]
```

**Application**

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from olcapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.get),
    url(r'^post/$',views.post),
    url(r'^show/([0-9]+)/$',views.getId),
    url(r'^update/([0-9]+)/$',views.update,name='update'),
    url(r'^delete/([0-9]+)/$',views.delete),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import CrudOperation
from .forms import CrudForm

# Create your views here.
def get(request):
    form = CrudForm()
    data = CrudOperation.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form,'data':data})

def getId(request,id):
    form = CrudForm()
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'form':form,'data':data})

def post(request):
    form = CrudForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>post Method</h1>')

def update(request,id):
    print(id)
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CrudForm(request.POST,instance=data)
    if(form.is_valid()):
        form.save()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>update method</h1>')

def delete(request,id):
    data = CrudOperation.objects.get(id=id)
    data.delete()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Delete method</h1>')
```

**Templates**

**index.html**

```
<h1> Registration Form </h1>
<form action="post/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<h1>List of all user</h1>  
<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {% for i in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ i.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ i.email}}</td>
          <td><a href="show/{{ i.id }}/">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="delete/{{ i.id }}/">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
```

**edit.html**

```
<h1> Update Form </h1>
<form action="update/{{ data.id }}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Name</label> 
    <input type="textbox" name="name" value="{{ data.name }}"> 
    <label>Email</label> 
    <input type="textbox" name="email" value="{{ data.email }}"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a Django application that performs CRUD operations, follow the following steps.
1. Create a Project
       $ django-admin startproject crudexample
2. Create an App
       $ python3 manage.py startapp employee
3. Project Structure

4.Run the command to migrate the migrations.

$ python3 manage.py migrate

5.Run Server
To run server use the following command.

$ python3 manage.py runserver

Access to the Browser
Access the application by entering localhost:8000/show, it will show all the available employee records.
Initially, there is no record.

Adding Record
Click on the Add New Record button and fill the details.

This section also allows, update and delete records from the actions column.
After saving couple of records, now we have following records.

Update Record
Lets update the record of x by clicking on edit button. It will display record of x in edit mode.

Lets, suppose I update x to x kumar then click on the update button. It updates the record immediately.
Click on update button and it redirects to the following page. See name is updated.
Same like, we can delete records too, by clicking the delete link.

Delete Record
Suppose, I want to delete x, it can be done easily by clicking the delete button.

Comment: @ İrem Simsar Thanks for your answer. But I already fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

import json
import psycopg2
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Get database connection information from environment variables
host = os.environ['DB_HOST']
port = os.environ['DB_PORT']
database = os.environ['DB_NAME']
user = os.environ['DB_USER']
password = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']

```
# Connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(host=host, port=port, database=database, user=user, password=password)
cur = conn.cursor()

# Retrieve HTTP method and resource path from the API Gateway event
http_method = event['httpMethod']
resource_path = event['resourcePath']

# Handle CRUD operations based on HTTP method and resource path
if http_method == 'GET' and resource_path == '/users':
    # Retrieve all users from the database
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    users = cur.fetchall()
    
    # Return the list of users as a JSON response
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(users)
    }
elif http_method == 'GET' and resource_path == '/users/{id}':
    # Retrieve a single user from the database based on the provided ID
    user_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=%s", (user_id,))
    user = cur.fetchone()
    
    # Return the user as a JSON response
    if user:
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(user)
        }
    else:
        return {
            'statusCode': 404,
            'body': json.dumps({'message': 'User not found'})
        }
elif http_method == 'POST' and resource_path == '/users':
    # Insert a new user into the database based on the provided data
    user_data = json.loads(event['body'])
    name = user_data['name']
    email = user_data['email']
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING id", (name, email))
    new_user_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
    conn.commit()
    
    # Return the ID of the new user as a JSON response
    return {
        'statusCode': 201,
        'body': json.dumps({'id': new_user_id})
    }
elif http_method == 'PUT' and resource_path == '/users/{id}':
    # Update an existing user in the database based on the provided data and ID
    user_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    user_data = json.loads(event['body'])
    name = user_data['name']
    email = user_data['email']
    cur.execute("UPDATE users SET name=%s, email=%s WHERE id=%s", (name, email, user_id))
    conn.commit()
    
    # Return a success message as a JSON response
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'User updated'})
    }
elif http_method == 'DELETE' and resource_path == '/users/{id}':
    # Delete an existing user from the database based on the provided ID
    user_id = event['pathParameters']['id']
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=%s", (user_id,))
    conn.commit()
    
    # Return a success message as a JSON response
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'
```

Comment: The style of the comments looks like this code was AI-generated. Please note that using ChatGPT to post answers is forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned